# How to do match exactly the content using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to match two string using PHP. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$fistno="9937229853";
$secondno="+919937229853";

?>
```

Here I need the value in `$fistno` is present in `$secondno` or not. If the value in `$fistno` is present in `$secondno` it will return true. In this case `9937229853` is present in `$secondno` so it should return true.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if (strpos($mystring, $findme) === false) {

    return false;
}

return true;
```

**Be careful** and use `=== false` as the string position in the other string can be `0` which when using `==` will evaluate to false when it is actually true.

Comment: what is `$mystring, $findme`.

Comment: `$mystring` is the string you are checking, `$findme` is the string you are trying to find in `$mystring`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strpos`

```
if (strpos($fistno, $secondno) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Strpost return -1 when string not find, 0 is the valid position

Comment: @DavinderKumar `strpos` __never__ returns -1. Read a manual please.

Comment: @DavinderKumar Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @DavinderKumar The Document clearly says **FALSE** is returned.

Comment: Yes, i was confused with js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` not just `=`

```
$check = 'this is a string 111';
if (strpos($mystring, $findme) === false) {
    echo 'perfect match';
} 
else {
    echo 'it did not match up';
}
```

`=` will assign the variable.
   `==` will do a loose comparison.
   `===` will do a strict comparison.